# use jquery variable in @ block razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm strugling with a jquery script inside a cshtml page. For short my question is how to use a var inside a @ statement in a cshtml page?

below an example of what I'm trying:

```
<select id="DefaultText">
    <option value="-1">-- select --</option>
    @foreach( var d in Model.DefaultTexts )
    {
        <option value="@d.Id" >@d.Name</option>
    }
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#DefaultText').change(function () {

        var id = parseInt($('#DefaultText :selected').val());
        var text = @Model.DefaultTexts.First( t => t.Id == id );

        $('#CustomProductText').val(text);
    });
</script>
```

I can't reach the var id. It's out of scope. I've also tryed it with a for loop and a if statement. But in the if statement I get the same error: out of scope.

The full story is this:
On my page I've a dropdown list. The items to select are short names for default text parts. Based on the id or name, I want to show the default text part in a textbox.

#CustomProductText is my textbox where the content should be placed (code not posted).

I've also tryed it with @: and  statement but that did not work.

What am I doing wrong or maybe its not even possible what I'm trying to do.

As an alternative I've added a action to my controller to get the text form there. Below the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#DefaultText').change(function () {

        var id = parseInt($('#DefaultText :selected').val());
        $.post("Categories/GetDefaultText", { Id: id }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });


        //$('#CustomProductText').val(text);
    });
</script>
```

controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetDefaultText(int id)
    {
        using( var context = new MyContext() )
        {
            var text = context.DefaultText.First( d => d.Id == id ).Text;
            return this.Content( text );
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work. The action doesn't get hit in debug mode.

regards,

Daniel

Comment: As a general piece of advice, Do not inject into JavaScript. It is maintenance nightmare and avoids any efficiencies you might otherwise get from script bundling. Instead inject values into page elements and pick those up with jQuery.

Comment: Since you already have the `Text` property of `DefaultTexts` you can just access it using javascript `$('#CustomProductText').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());` (you don't need to call a controller method) but whats the point of displaying it both the dropdown and another element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.post` that is not working for you, you should prefix the url with `/` sign and it will be hit as expected:

```
$.post("/Categories/GetDefaultText", { Id: id }, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

As for the razor solution, you can't use javascript variables in the razor code as it's not a scripting language. What razor does is simply rendering the strings (be it html or javascript or anything) into the page.

To do what you want you either need to request the server to pass the text to your page or render all the texts you have in the page and then access this rendered content in your javascript.

Comment: Making the URL absolute may not work when deployed to a web application that is not under the domain root.

Comment: Adding the / sign worked out for me. Thanks! But your solution with the single quotes did not work. I still get the message that id does not exists in the current context. I prefer the linq option because the data is already loaded in the page. Can you help me out with the quotes? Am I missing some special libraries??

Comment: @danielkaya I've re-read your question, you can't access javascript variables from razor, see my updated answer.